# Cart is empty when customer logged-in

Tags: magento-1.6, session, cookie, ce-1.6.2.0

I'm using Magento ver.1.6.2.0.

I'm adding some items into the cart without logging-in. After that I am logging in. After getting logged in, Cart shows 0 items.

When I check in chrome developer tool-> resources->cookies. Cookie 'Frontend' is not created. Is it may be a problem?

I could not get idea. Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the values under `System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Management` or correct.

`cookie path` should be either empty or **/**

`cookie domain` should be either empty or the correct domain. if your URL is `www.example.com` the cookie domain should be `.www.example.com`

Comment: it is not working

Comment: I'm gonna need a little bit more than that to help you debug. Please check the logs from apache, php and magento for possible errors

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with google chrome, where if you put an item in the cart it 'disappeared' once you logged in and logging in would simply make the login screen refresh.  If you tried to login first, then you would constantly get the login screen refreshing and not be able to add any item to the cart until, I'm guessing, the token time expired.

This issue only affect google chrome over https and not over http, chrome worked fine over http. Explorer or Firefox worked fine with both http and https.

The above simple fix worked a treat.

Adam